# With ajax pass drop down menu values to php, in php process and get back (can not see all values that expected to see)

Tags: php, ajax

Within `php while` is such drop down menu

```
<tr id='row<?php echo $row_number;?>'>
    ...
    <td>
        <select name="currency[]" id="currency<?php echo $row_number;?>" >
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In `html` output get multiple such menus (because of `php while`)

With `ajax` trying to pass the values to external php file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function sendCurrencies() {

        function autosave(suffix) {
            if (($("#currency" + suffix).val()).length > 0) {
                alert($("#currency" + suffix).val());

                $.post(
                    "__foreign_currency_rate.php",
                    $("#row" + suffix + " :input").serialize(),
                    function (data) { $('#load' + suffix).html(data); }
                );
            }//if ( ($("#currency" + suffix).val()).length > 0 ) {
        }//function autosave(suffix) {

        $('[id^="currency"]').each(function (index, currency) {
            var suffix = currency.id.substring(8);
            autosave(suffix);
        });

    }//function sendCurrencies() {

    setInterval(sendCurrencies, 6000);
});//$(document).ready(function() {
```

Suppose problem/question may be in this part of code `$.post("__foreign_currency_rate.php", $("#row" + suffix + " :input").serialize(),`

In external `php` file at first want to check what I get

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['currency']);
echo '</pre>';
```

For example `php while` 3 loops, so get 3 drop down menus. In first select AUD, second EUR, third USD.

With `print_r($_POST['currency']);` expect to see all values.

But see only two values

```
Array
(
    [0] => EUR
)

Array
(
    [0] => AUD
)
```

But with `alert($("#currency" + suffix).val());` pop up menu displays all values.

Where is problem why with `php` can not see all values?

For not understandable reasons `$("#row" + suffix + " :input").serialize()` passes only 2 values...

Tried to record drop down menu values in `mysql`. All values recorded. But with `print_r` does not print all values. something crazy....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $.post("__foreign_currency_rate.php", $("#currency" + suffix + "   :input").serialize(), function(data) {
$('#load' + suffix).html(data);
  });
```

Comment: Prints nothing. And if change to `print_r($_POST);` then prints 2 empty arrays